# Change date format in scheduler navigation for kendo ui

Tags: kendo-ui, scheduler, date-formatting

I'm searching for the possibility to change date format of kendo ui scheduler components' navigation bar. In the basic exmaple ([click here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/index)) you can see the selected time range right next to "Today" button. I don't have so much space left in my website and therefore want to change date format to eg. "18.08.2014 - 24.08.2014". 
Unfortunately I don't see any option to configure this in the official [api reference](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/scheduler)...

Did I just overlook something or is it not possible to change settings for that?

Thanks for your help.

Philip

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem, I noticed with Chrome dev tools there is a span with class="k-lg-date-format" wich displays the date as you see it now, and a span with class="k-sm-date-format" that could display the date with the shorter MM/dd/yyyy format, but his display property is set to none. I created another stylesheet to change the display property of the first to none and the second to inline. Had to use !importan because it was overloaded by kendo stylesheet.

```
.k-sm-date-format {
    display: inline !important;
}

.k-lg-date-format {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's configurable:

```
views: [
            {
                type: CustomAgenda,
                title: "List",
                selected: true,
                selectedDateFormat: "{0:dddd dd MMMM yyyy} - {1:dddd dd MMMM yyyy}",
                selectedShortDateFormat: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy} - {1:dd/MM/yyyy}"
            }, {
                type: "day",
                selectedDateFormat: "{0:dddd dd MMMM yyyy}",
                selectedShortDateFormat: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"
            }, {
                type: "month",
                selectedDateFormat: "{0:MMMM yyyy}",
                selectedShortDateFormat: "{0:MMMM yyyy}"
            }
        ]
```

The short format is for crossing the low width responsive break point.

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler/configuration/views.selecteddateformat